# How do I tackle phone-microcontroller BlueTooth communication?

Tags: microcontroller, communication, spi, bluetooth, stm32

I have [this bluetooth module](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/0f44/0900766b80f441e6.pdf) I bought on RS a while back, and I was pretty keen to set it up with an STM32L152 development board I have handy. The only thing is, I'm not really sure what steps I have to take to get to that point, I'm finding the whole datasheet very overwhelming.

I can handle the SPI communication stuff, or at least figure it out eventually on my own, but the bluetooth protocols/handshakes, etc. are a total mystery to me and I don't have a clue how to go about even pairing the module with my phone which would be a step towards my eventual goal.

Suggestions, advice, links, and ideas that can help me get to where I want to be would all be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, Bluetooth modules have a so-called "AT" interface, meaning you can send commands to them and results back using AT commands modeled after the old Hayes modems of decades ago.  But I was unable to find any such interface for this module.

As far as I can tell, the RFM70 module is *not* Bluetooth -- it operates in the 2400-2483.5 MHz ISM (Industrial Scientific Medical) band, which is the same frequency band used by Bluetooth but using different protocols.  People are using the RFM70 to "talk" from one microcontroller to another (for example, remote control of a device), but not to communicate to and from Bluetooth devices.

I see where RS Online was [claiming it is Bluetooth](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/bluetooth-modules/7312795/), but its not.

There are many libraries out there to help to interface to a RFM70, but most seem to be for the Arduino.  However [I was able to find one,](http://www.voti.nl/rfm70/) while not targeting the STM32 directly, seems to have been ported to several different micros so perhaps you can modify it for your use.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply, very helpful. That's a bit of a pain though... I guess it's pretty useless to me then unless I have another the same, or another using the same communication standard? Don't suppose you have any recommendations for a different bluetooth module/IC?

Comment: @Kureigu - Sparkfun has quite, few including [this one](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11601).  Read the comments below the product description for links to tutorials etc. You can do a search or "Bluetooth" on their site to find others.